# How to show "modified" date in Page Layout?

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-page

I have made a custom page layout in which I have added the following fields (these are my custom fields)

- title
- summary
- detail

So basically when a user creates a new page based on this page layout he has to enter the above fields.

I want to show `"created"` date on that page? I mean when user creates a page, it should automatically get "created" date and show on page.

Or if it cannot be done automatically, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Add created, modified fields to your page layout content type and add those fields in layout. Find the fields code snippet in design manager and place it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="CreatedOn" FieldName="Created" runat="server" />
```

But most often people use the publishing start date like this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:PublishingScheduleFieldControl FieldName="PublishingStartDate" InputFieldLabel="Scheduling Start Date" runat="server" />
```